.NET Core and framework share particular session variables by SystemWebAdapter
Our ASP.NET Webforms projects have many session variables. Per SystemWebAdapter, I need to list of them by AddJsonSessionSerializer in Application_Start.
Is it possible that I can limit them to that used in .NET Core project only?
I have tried not listing them all and got this error: "Unknown session keys
Here is the ASP.NET code snap with two session variables: Company and Employee. But only Employee is set to share
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemWebAdapterConfiguration.AddSystemWebAdapters(this)
        .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options => {
            options.RegisterKey<ArrayList>("Employee");
        })
        .AddRemoteAppServer(
            options => {
                options.ApiKey = "4ffb49b3-2aa3-40b3-96ca-1b5331aab2dc";
            }
        ).AddSessionServer();
}

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Company"] = "ABC";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Employee"] = "John";
}

Here is program.cs:
using Core;
using System.Collections;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddTransient<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters()
    .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options => {
        options.RegisterKey<ArrayList>("Employee");
    })
    .AddRemoteAppClient(options => {
        options.RemoteAppUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.56.1");
        options.ApiKey = "4ffb49b3-2aa3-40b3-96ca-1b5331aab2dc";
    }).AddSessionClient();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Thanks

After testing in my local, I found seems you are missing RequireSystemWebAdapterSession, maybe you are using [Session] attribute in your controller. And there is not Company Register Key information in your webform application.
Here is the working sample for you.
WebForm
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SystemWebAdapterConfiguration.AddSystemWebAdapters(this)
           .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options => {
               options.RegisterKey<string>("Company");
               options.RegisterKey<ArrayList>("Employee");
           })
           .AddRemoteAppServer(options =>
           {
               options.ApiKey = "68aba9ab-0d19-4b0a-952e-70a84f5113c2";
           })
           .AddSessionServer();
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}

Default.aspx.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Company"] = "ABC";
            ArrayList employeeData = new ArrayList();
            employeeData.Add("John Doe");
            employeeData.Add("Jane Smith");
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Employee"] = employeeData;
        }
    }
}

ASP.NET CORE API
using System.Collections;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});


builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters()
    .AddJsonSessionSerializer(options => {
        options.RegisterKey<string>("Company");
        options.RegisterKey<ArrayList>("Employee");
    })
    .AddRemoteAppClient(options => {
        options.RemoteAppUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44394"); 
        options.ApiKey = "68aba9ab-0d19-4b0a-952e-70a84f5113c2";
    }).AddSessionClient();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();

app.MapControllers().RequireSystemWebAdapterSession();

app.Run();

SessionTestController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters;
using System.Collections;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SessionTestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetSessionValue")]
        public IActionResult GetSessionValue()
        {
            var sessionValue = System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Session?["Company"].ToString();
            if (sessionValue == null)
            {
                return NotFound("Company not found in session.");
            }

            return Ok(new { TestSession = sessionValue });
        }
        [HttpGet("GetEmployeeData")]
        public IActionResult GetEmployeeData()
        {
            var employeeData = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session?["Employee"] as ArrayList;
            if (employeeData == null)
            {
                return NotFound("Employee data not found in session.");
            }

            return Ok(new { Employee = employeeData });
        }
    }
    
}

Test Result


Yes, I am using [Session] for the endpoint that need session info.  In your global.ascx and program.cs, if you only share, for example, "Employee" session variable, you will see the error..  "Unknown session keys: Company

Hi @user25654022 , I also found it. Will investigate the issue when I am free.
